# Click through nav handler eslint errors

Tags: reactjs, eslint-config-airbnb

I have a sliding-menu component.
It has items and I want to hide the menu when I click on each item. But if i click on 
Now I did so:

```js
<nav onClick={this.handleClickCloseMenu}>
  <Link
    to="/smth"
    activeClassName="is-active"
  >
    smth
  </Link>
  <Link
    to="/smth2"
    activeClassName="is-active"
  >
    smth2
  </Link>
</nav>
```

Now I have an eslint errors: `jsx-a11y/no-noninteractive-element-interactions` end `jsx-a11y/no-static-element-interactions`
I can set role button to `nav` but i guess it is wrong way. What do you think about?

Comment: Are you talking about hiding `nav` when current `url` is `/smth` or `/smth2`? Use a router for that

Comment: What do you mean? Handle a click on the Link and there hide the menu?

Comment: I mean you just could render you `nav` only when `path='/' exact`

Comment: But I want to be able to open the menu on every page. And when you click on the item menu, the menu becomes hidden. It is sliding menu.

Comment: I just want handle each click on nav and dispatch a hide menu action(The menu opens elsewhere).

Comment: Got it, take a look at this: https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#disabling-rules-with-inline-comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought a little and decided to tie into the `key` parameter, it's generated by `react-router`. In `componentDidUpdate`, look at the `key` and if the current one differs from the previous one, then hide the menu. If it is open of course.  streletss thank you for pushing a thought